# How to convert a string to Floating point number and then sort the numbers in ascending order in a multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of strings like:

```
$array = array(
    array('km' => '25 Km', 'name' => 'B'),
    array('km' => '1.2 Km', 'name' => 'A'),
    array('km' => '7.7 Km', 'name' => 'Q'),
    array('km' => '107 Km', 'name' => 'M'),
    array('km' => '0.1 Km', 'name' => 'R'),
    array('km' => '20 Km', 'name' => 'J'),
    array('km' => '20.3 Km', 'name' => 'HH'))
```

How can I convert key `km` into floating point numbers then sort `$array` in an ascending number based on the KEY `km`?

Comment: You want to sort by the closest value (in km)?

Comment: With `(float)` type cast?

Comment: Yes I want to sort by KM in ascending order

Comment: @u_mulder, I tried float casting but it fails, maybe I was not doing it right

Comment: Then maybe you should show us the code you tried and we might be able to spot the issue

Comment: Is the anything invalid in my question if I may ask?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, the question is answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `usort` callback it is:

```
usort(
    $array, 
    function($a, $b) { return (float)$a['km'] <=> (float)$b['km']; }
);
```

If `<=>` is not available:

```
usort(
    $array, 
    function($a, $b) { return (float)$a['km'] - (float)$b['km']; }
);
```